# Iterating across a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, foreach, try-catch

I have several sites from which I want to get information with BeautifulSoup. The list of sites will change as time goes on. Also, some sites may not have relevant information at the time.

I fill in the urls of relevant sites and leave the others blank.

```
site1 = "http://www.some-site.com"
site2 = "http://www.another-site.com"
site3 = ""
site4 = "http://www.still-another-site.com"
```

I can manually get the "soup" from each url with these. I have `except` statements
to handle the missing urls.

```
try:
    source_site1 = requests.get(site1, headers=hdr).text
    soup_site1 = BeautifulSoup(source_site1, "lxml")
try:
    source_site2 = requests.get(site2, headers=hdr).text
    soup_site2 = BeautifulSoup(source_site2, "lxml")
try:
    source_site3 = requests.get(site3, headers=hdr).text
    soup_site3 = BeautifulSoup(source_site3, "lxml")
try:
    source_site4 = requests.get(site4, headers=hdr).text
    soup_site4 = BeautifulSoup(source_site4, "lxml")
```

Is there a way to group the urls and iterate across the group to get the "soup" for each site without having to hard-code each one (like above)?

If not, is there another method that will give the same results (a separate "soup" variable for each site)?

I tried this but the "for" loop is stumping me.

```
site_list_dict = {
    site1:  "http://www.some-site1.com",
    site2:"http://www.some-site2.com"
    site3:""
    site4:"http://www.some-site4.com"
}

# (This will not work because it will be overwritten with each pass. I would need a unique name for
#   each "soup" variable, preferably assocated with the site key.)
for key,value in site_list_dict():
    try:
        source = requests.get(value, headers=hdr).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
```

Comment: You can store those `soup` variables in a dictionary similar to the one storing your URLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mySoups = dict()
for key,value in site_list_dict:
    try:
        source = requests.get(value, headers=hdr).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
        mySoups[key] = soup
```

Comment: When I tried this, I got an error.
`TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`

Adding ".items" worked.
`for key, value in sites_list_dict.items():`

Now I have a new dict with the original keys and associated soups to work with. This solves my issue.

Comment: My typo. Actually had copied your snippet.

Answer (score -1):

You can try storing your urls like:

```
url_dict = {
        "site1": "http://www.url1.com",
        "site2": "http://www.url2.com",
        "site3": "http://www.url3.com",
        "site4": "http://www.url4.com",
    }
```

If you don't like the for loop, you can generalize the function and then map it.

```
def send_request(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers={"content-type":"text"})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml")
        return soup
    except Exception as e:
        raise e

list_of_soups = list(map(send_request, list(url_dict.values())))
# Map it onto a dict directly:
url_dict_final = dict(map(lambda item: (item[0], send_request(item[1])), url_dict.items()))
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem OP mentioned in the question.

Comment: "Is there a way to group the urls and iterate across the group to get the "soup" for each site without having to hard-code each one (like above)?

If not, is there another method that will give the same results (a separate "soup" variable for each site)?"

Comment: The "to get the "soup" for each site" part. You can check the other answer (or your second piece of code to some extent) for a complete solution